# modify several bits at once without wrecking operation - 8051 ports

Tags: input, output, bit, 8051

I'm trying to figure out if there's a simple way to modify several bits of an 8051 port at once.

I'll re-explain my dilemma more concrete style.

My application has Port 2 divided for two functions. Let's call them FA and FB.

FA relies on the output value of the low three bits, and FB relies on the remaining 5 bits but they can be I/O.

Because one bit in FB is an output bit that controls a clock, I don't want to modify any part of FB when I'm modifying FA and vice-versa.

The following kinds of commands won't work for me:

```
mov P2,#07h
mov P2,#80h
```

This is because such commands will overwrite the values for both functions possibly triggering one function at the wrong time.

I could get away with something like the following:

```
setb P2.7
setb P2.6
clr P2.5
clr P2.4
setb P2.3
setb P2.2
clr P2.1
clr P2.0
```

Because I know those commands can set individual bits one by one without affecting the remaining bits, but I'd like to try to set more than one bit at a time.

I read about read-modify-write and the internet tells me MOV is different from logic operations on port pins, so I'm going to try to take a guess here to see if I'm right based on my example:

Say for FB I want to output all logic highs and for FA I want to output all logic lows except that lowest bit=1. I want to operate on one function at a time.

I know this won't work since it sets everything at once:

```
mov P2, #0F9h
```

But somehow I think using logic on the ports might work, but I want to know if my thinking is correct. Let's assume in the two cases below that P2 has the value set to #0A1h via the mov command, and the pins of P2 are all connected to ground.

Is this correct?:

```
anl P2,#F8h ;value of P2 = #0A1h AND #F8h = #0A0h
orl P2,#F9h ;value of P2 = #0A0h OR #F9h = #0F9h
anl P2,#F0h ;value of P2 = #0F9h AND #F0h = #0F0h
```

Or is this more correct?:

```
anl P2,#F8h ;value of P2 = #00h AND #F8h = #00h
orl P2,#F9h ;value of P2 = #00h OR #F9h = #0F9h
anl P2,#F0h ;value of P2 = #00h AND #F0h = #00h
```

In the second example I started the equations with #00h because thats the value P2 would produce if I used MOV A,P2 and then wanted value for A, but I'm not sure if that value will be used in the anl and orl calculations.

So overall, **my question is, can I use anl and orl to modify only certain bits of a port without disturbing the rest of the bits? or am I stuck with using bit manipulation commands like setb and clr?**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to add the following aspect. The approach involving SETB and CLR instructions will require more machine cycles to execute, and might be infeasible in some cases (ie. clock generation, sync issues).

The 8051 ports are rather primitive compared to contemporary MCUs. The 'port' has a latch that stores the pin state and that latch tries to condition the output. This does not necessarily mean that the port is at desired state. For instance if it is driven low externally the latch may be high but the port will be low. This is exactly how we set a port to be an input.

When we MOVe data to a port, we write to the latch, when we MOVe from the port into a register, we read the actual state regardless of the state of the latch. Read-modify-write operations are an exception to this, as they specifically read the latch, perform desired operation and write back to the latch. Therefore the scenario given under "Is this correct?:" is the correct one.

If instead we were to MOV A, P2 and then execute anl P2,#F8h "Or is this more correct?:" would be correct.

As a result we can use logic operations to modify ports for the cases given in this question.

Comment: I must be then better off to use this coding approach if I put my custom value in R7's high nibble and want to make it as the high nibble of Port 2 actual output while leaving the lower nibble of Port 2 unchanged:  `MOV R7,#70h  MOV A,P2  ANL A,#0Fh  ORL A,R7  MOV P2,A`. Am I on the right track?